# How can I create a while loop in Powershell to count number less than 10 up to 0

Tags: powershell, while-loop

I am not sure how while loops works in Powershell. I need help in creating a while loop that counts numbers in Powershell from 10..0.

```
 $a -eq 10
 while $a -lt 10
 { $a--}
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paxdiablo answered your question and pointed out the flaws in your code and logic quite nicely. I only add this answer as a simple alternative to the `While` loop for something as easy as counting down from 10 to 0. PowerShell will iterate numbers from a start point to an end point by doing NumberA..NumberB or in your case:

```
10..0
```

From there you can pipe into a ForEach loop if you want to do something with those numbers, such as:

```
10..0 | ForEach{"Launch in T minus $_";start-sleep -sec 1};"Blast-off!"
```

Please consider this answer purely educational.

Answer (score 3):

For a start, `$a -eq 10` does not set `$a` to ten, it evaluates the expression "does `$a` equal ten" and gives you a true/false value. What you need is:

```
$a = 10
```

Secondly, even if you set it to ten correctly, your while loop will only start if it's less than ten, which it isn't. And that's actually a *good* thing since it would then run for a very long time :-)

Instead you need to continue while it's greater than or equal to zero.

Based on that information, you can count from 10 down to 0 with:

```
PS C:\Pax> $a = 10; while ($a -ge 0) { echo $a; $a--; }
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

You can also use the more Powershell-ish:

```
10..0 | foreach { echo $_; }
```

Comment: @sa99 if you feel that he answered your question please mark his answer as accepted (the checkmark near the up/down votes to the left of his answer).

Comment: @paxdiablo This is great!! Could you please point out the format as in While loops need to begin with a statement of $a=0 because ....... then next step is to test for condition as in ($a -ge 0) and the reason we use echo and not write-host or we can use both as in {......} This is for educational reasons only, if possible.OR if you can point to   online resource /textbook. Much Appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop like this in PowerShell.

```
PS> (10..0)|%{$_}
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```